# Subdomain ASP.Net API project under another ASP.Net MVC project

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, dns, subdomain

I'm building a website/API.  I have two ASP.Net Core 3.1 projects:

- MyProject.Site
- MyProject.Api

They are both hosted in Azure as App Services:

- `myproject.api.azurewebsites.net`
- `myproject.site.azurewebsites.net`

Finally `myproject.site.azurewebsites.net` is mapped to my custom domain, `https://myproject.com`.

What I'd like to do is set up `https://api.myproject.com` to resolve to `myproject.api.azurewebsites.net`, but I can't see how to associate the two now that I have the primary domain linked to the site.

I have an A record for `api` with my domain registrar, but I noticed within Azure that both app services have the same IP address listed under the *Custom Domains* pane. (I would expect them to have different IPs since they're different sites.)

When I go to set up a subdomain on the domain registrar, it's asking for a directory, which I assume would be something like `/api` to indicate `https://api.myproject.com` would reroute to `https://myproject.com/api`.  But that wouldn't that mean that I'd need to expose my API project through the `/api` route on my site project?

I'm new to domains and basic infrastructur-y stuff, so explanations of solutions are appreciated.

(I also had originally considered putting the API and the site in the same project.  Then I probably wouldn't have this problem.  But I soon found that I needed different authentication methods between them, so I split them to accommodate this requirement.)

Comment: You should be able to create a CNAME record for api that points to myproject.api.azurewebsites.net - This would be done in your domain management and you don't need to worry about a folder, this sounds like the domain registrar also does hosting.

Comment: Just in case you haven't already seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Comment: Do I need to remove the A record, or just add the CNAME?

Comment: Yes, if you have A for api, you need to remove it first then add the CNAME for api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SmithMart 's comment, you just need to create a `CNAME` record for the `api` subdomain that points to another App Service `myproject.api.azurewebsites.net` in your domain management.

You don't worry about the directory, DNS will help resolve the name `api.myproject.com` to your real site `myproject.api.azurewebsites.net`.

You could follow the [Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain). You will get

- [Map a subdomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-cname-record) (for example, [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com)) by using a `CNAME` record
- [Map a root domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-an-a-record) (for example, contoso.com) by using an `A` record